# Xcode dependency anaylsis error

Tags: ios, xcode

On my Xcode project, I tried to compile. But I couldn't do that because of some errors
Those are like as follows.

Unable to run command 'CpResource XXX.app' - this target might include its own product.
Unable to run command 'Touch XXX.app' - this target might include its own product.

So I tried to clean project, but I couldn't do that also.
How can I fix these errors?
Hope your help. Thanks.

Comment: Im not entirely clear from your question. Can you post a screen shot of your IDE with the file selected?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to your Products folder and make sure your .app file has no Target Memberships in the file inspector. Nothing should be checked. I had the same issue and that fixed it for me.